# Sprite Kit Action for Score Label Animation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, scale, skaction

as you can see below, i try to run an action which increases the size of my ScoreLabel, whenever the score increases. When i run my app, i realized, that the size of my label doesn't set back to his original form. I tried many ways, but couldnt realize it

I hope for you quick answers

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    // Update wird vor jeden Frame aufgerufen


    // Score Counter
    if( [speerArray count] > 1) {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [speerArray objectAtIndex:1];
        if (sprite.position.y < superhero.position.y && [sprite.name isEqualToString:@"speer"] && sprite.position.y > 0) {

            SKAction* scoreAction = [SKAction  scaleBy:2 duration:1];



            score ++;
            [scoreLabel runAction:scoreAction];


            scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score/2];




            sprite.name = @"afterBird";
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's "original form" mean and where is it suppose to revert?

Comment: You are scaling the label up to twice its size but never scaling it down again. Run another action to scale it by 0.5 in a sequence after scoreAction.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following lines might be what you are looking for:

```
[scoreLabel removeAllActions];
SKAction* scoreAction = [SKAction scaleBy:2 duration:1];
SKAction* revertAction = [SKAction scaleTo:1 duration:1];
SKAction* completeAction = [SKAction sequence:@[scoreAction, revertAction]];
[scoreLabel runAction:completeAction];
```

You can put in a `waitForDuration:` action as well, if required.